# Non-Searchable text in PDFs in OSX (10.10.3)

Tags: macos, pdf, itext, osx-yosemite

Since last summer, there is a very strange problem with my bank - the textual content of their statements of account (PDF files) isn't readable under OSX. The PDFs are since then (2014) produced in a new way:
Info in Preview.app delivers `pdf produced with: iText 2.0.8 (by lowagie.com), content produced with -void-` .
[Before it was `pdf produced with: iText 1.4 (by lowagie.com), content produced with JasperReports (kontoauszug)]`
I couldn't believe the answer of the technical support (answer#1) of the bank [postbank.de, 14.5 millions of customers] – that changing to MSWindows would eliminate the problem. Today I made the test: all textual content is precisely represented and searchable on a standard Windows 7 system, while the same data delivers hits only for single or double characters, a search for 'the' typically delivers no single result under OS X – while being selectable and (falsely) copyable.
Technical support (answer#2) was: working with high priority on that problem – that is from last winter, nothing happened.
Can I do anything?

Comment: What did you use to view the PDF on Windows 7? Have you tried one of these files in Adobe Reader on Mac to see if that works? Preview on Mac OS X has a relatively unique view on what should be supported and what not as far as PDFs go (and that's putting it nicely)...

Comment: Also: please have the bank contact iText Group NV. The lowagie.com you mention, that's me. iText 2.0.8 dates from January 2008. They should upgrade to the latest version. It's not a good idea to use a version that old.